# Wildfly hot deploy too slow

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, wildfly

I decided to check out Wildfly 8.2.0-Final as an application server instead of Glassfish 4.1 as I've heard good things about its speed.

The first thing I did was to create a normal Java EE web application (ant based for now, but I will look into using maven). Compile-on-save is switched on in NetBeans 8.0.2.

However, to my dismay, if I change static content or change the content of a simple REST service such as:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getText() {
    return "Foobar";
}
```

It takes up to several seconds before the change become visible.  I could *almost* live with this for Java classes, but for static content I'd like immediate feedback as I do a lot of incremental small changes.

This usually takes about 200ms on Glassfish (exactly the same code), so I don't understand it's up to 10x slower on Wildfly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume from the description that you're deploying to `standalone/deployments`. The changes made in that folder are picked up by the deployment scanner which, fortunately, is configurable.

[There is a very good description in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Scanner+configuration), but the important part is that you need to lower the scan interval.

If you've never used the JBoss CLI before, you might be interested to know that there's a GUI mode for it. In the bin directory, call the jboss-cli.sh script with the `-c` option to connect to your local server and the `--gui` option to start the gui:

```
<WFLY_HOME>/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --gui
```

[image: JBoss CLI GUI]

As you can see in the image above, you can expand the deployment scanner subsystem, then right click the scan-interval attribute and select "write attribute" to open the dialog below.

Lower the number (500ms = half a second), click OK, and remember to click "Submit" in the top right to actually apply your change.